# Bootstrap : Slideup/ Slidedown or Accordion in Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel heading and a panel body having a description by default when the page reloads. when I click on the **+** symbol then there are some contents to be displayed and that description to be removed.

everything is working fine. but when I **slideup** then the description is appeared but it appears suddenly with a kind of stroke.

I can do it using `time unit` but it adds fade-in effect to it. which i don't want.

```js
$('.add_discount_plus_minus').on('click', function () {
  if($(this).text() === "+" ) {
    $(this).text("-");
    $('.club_registration_plus_minus').text("+");
    $('.settings_plus_minus').text("+");
    $('.add_discount_one_line_description').hide();
    $('.show_hide_add_discount_panel').slideDown();
  } else {
    $(this).text("+");
    /*$(this).css('font-size' , '20px');*/
    $('.show_hide_add_discount_panel').slideUp();
    $('.add_discount_one_line_description').show();
  }
})
```

```css
.add_discount_plus_minus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.show_hide_add_discount_panel {
  display: none;
}

.set_padding_0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.set_margin_0 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default set_padding_0">

  <div class="panel-heading text-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <span>Add Discount</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <span class="pull-right cursor_pointer add_discount_plus_minus font-bold font_size_17">+</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body ">
    <div class="row set_margin_0">
      <span class="add_discount_one_line_description"> Code, Offer Name, Discount Amount, Uses Per Offer, Group Discounts </span>
    </div>
    <div class="show_hide_add_discount_panel ">
      <div class="row margin_top_10 set_margin_0">
        <span>Some contents to be displayed</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row margin_top_10 set_margin_0">
        <span>Some contents to be displayed</span>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbxqsxjp/)

When you slide up the panel body then the description gets displayed suddenly. 
How can i solve it?

Any help would b great.

Thank You.

Comment: what exactly you want? default contents to be shown or not?

Comment: yes.. it should be shown. when the page reloads then one line description is to be there. right?. then when clicking on + symbol **some contents** to be displayed which is i m getting perfect. but at the time of slideup. the description gets suddenly appears with a kind of stroke.

Comment: try adding timeout before showing default content if you dont want to use any fade in effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use timeout, it will be hard to match exactly the time it takes to slide. The [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) method has a callback function to call once the animation is complete, show your default content there

```
$('.show_hide_add_discount_panel').slideUp(function(){
   $('.add_discount_one_line_description').show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hbxqsxjp/2/

Comment: Thank you... just one more thing. I want **+** and **-** text to be the same. like when I click on **+** then **-** symbol is slightly left. I want both of them to be on the same position. it should seem that just only one vertical line is getting removed from text.

Comment: Set a width, line-height and text-align to center. Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hbxqsxjp/3/

Comment: yes.. thank you.. can't I have **-** text little bit bigger when opening panel?

Comment: That's a different question, I suggest you mark this one as answered and open a new one with other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should try to add some `timeout` before you see the default content.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qaeed/hbxqsxjp/1/

```js
$('.add_discount_plus_minus').on('click', function () {
  if($(this).text() === "+" ) {
    $(this).text("-");
    $('.club_registration_plus_minus').text("+");
    $('.settings_plus_minus').text("+");
    $('.add_discount_one_line_description').hide();
    $('.show_hide_add_discount_panel').slideDown();
  } else {
    $(this).text("+");
    /*$(this).css('font-size' , '20px');*/
    $('.show_hide_add_discount_panel').slideUp();
        setTimeout(function(){
     $('.add_discount_one_line_description').show();
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```css
.add_discount_plus_minus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.show_hide_add_discount_panel {
  display: none;
}

.set_padding_0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.set_margin_0 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default set_padding_0">

  <div class="panel-heading text-left">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <span>Add Discount</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <span class="pull-right cursor_pointer add_discount_plus_minus font-bold font_size_17">+</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body ">
    <div class="row set_margin_0">
      <span class="add_discount_one_line_description"> Code, Offer Name, Discount Amount, Uses Per Offer, Group Discounts </span>
    </div>
    <div class="show_hide_add_discount_panel ">
      <div class="row margin_top_10 set_margin_0">
        <span>Some contents to be displayed</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row margin_top_10 set_margin_0">
        <span>Some contents to be displayed</span>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: yes got it... just one more thing. I want **+** and **-** text to be the same. like when I click on **+** then **-** symbol is slightly left. I want both of them to be on the same position. it should seem that just only one vertical line is getting removed from text.

Comment: @Rishi use standard icon classes instead of using + & -. You will get unified user interface across the browsers. https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/ Also please accept answer if that helped you.

Comment: yes.. i have visited this link. but i don't know , how to use in jquery. how can i apply that class when panel is opened..?